# Is it always true that the integral of cos and sin to an odd power from $0$ to $2\pi$ is always $0$?

Tags: integration

Is it always true $\int^{2\pi}_0 \sin^{2m+1}(x) dx=0$,$\int^{2\pi}_0 \cos^{2m+1}(x) dx=0$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

I am thinking this must be the case considering how the graph behaves.

Comment: So in general, did you mean $\sin^{2k+1}(x)$ or $\cos^{2k+1}(x)$ for an integer $k$? Or $\sin(cx)$ is also allowed for some $c$ for instance?

Comment: Use the trig identity $\sin(x)=-\sin(x+\pi)$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr as in the integral is odd about $x= \pi$ and hence the the integral is 0?

Comment: @ArsenBerk the first one. It's edited now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Let $m$ odd.

For $sin$, note that $$\int_0^\pi\sin^m(x)dx=-\int_\pi^{2\pi}\sin^m(x)dx$$

For $cos$, note that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$$
$$\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\cos^m(x)dx=-\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$$

(You may graph it to convince yourself that this is the case)

Answer (score 1):

Julian's hint/answer is good and that's an easier way to arrive at your conclusion. Here I will try to offer you an alternative way to see it:

Remember that, by using integration by parts, you can get that:

$$ \int sin^m(x) dx = -\frac{1}{m}\cos(x)\sin^{m-1}(x) + \frac{m-1}{m} \int \sin^{m-2}x dx $$

Hence, if $m = 2k+1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then by the above reduction formula you can see that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} sin^{2k+1}(x) dx =  \bigg[-\frac{1}{2k+1}\cos(x)\sin^{2k}(x)\bigg]_0^{2\pi} + \frac{2k}{2k+1} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k-1}x dx \\
=  0  + \frac{2k}{2k+1} \bigg( \bigg[-\frac{1}{2k-1}\cos(x)\sin^{2k-2}(x)\bigg]_0^{2\pi} 
+ \frac{2k-2}{2k-1}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k-3} dx  \bigg) \hspace{2.5 cm} \\
= 0 +  \frac{2k}{2k+1} \bigg( 0
+ \frac{2k-2}{2k-1} \bigg(\bigg[-\frac{1}{2k-3}\cos(x)\sin^{2k-4}(x)\bigg]_0^{2\pi}   
 + \frac{2k-4}{2k-3} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k-5} dx \bigg) \bigg) \\
= \cdots \hspace{15.8 cm} \\
=  \frac{2k}{2k+1} \bigg(\frac{2k-2}{2k-1} \bigg(\frac{2k-4}{2k-3}\bigg( \cdots    
 \bigg(\frac{2}{3} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{1} dx \bigg) \cdots \bigg)  \\
= \frac{2k}{2k+1} \bigg(\frac{2k-2}{2k-1} \bigg(\frac{2k-4}{2k-3}\bigg( \cdots    
 \bigg(\frac{2}{3} \bigg(0\bigg) \bigg) \cdots \bigg) = 0 \\
$$
Therefore,

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} sin^{2k+1}(x) dx = 0 $$

Similarly, you can derive the reduction formula for $\cos^m{x}$ using integration by parts, and you should get

$$ \int cos^{m} x dx = \frac{1}{m}\cos^{m-1}(x) \sin(x) + \frac{n-1}{n} \int \cos^{n-2} x dx  $$

From, here you can replicate what I did above and show that for $m = 2k +1$, you will also get the that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2k+1} x dx = 0$$

Yes, this is a long way of getting the answer, but like I said, this is an alternative way of seeing why it should be 0. Hopefully that helps.